# How to get data or selected tags from Materialize Chips to Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, tags, materialize, chips

I've been trying to get the tags selected in a Chips field of Materialize CSS, but without success, can anyone help me?

**Full HTML Template:**

```
<form action="{{ url_for('add') }}" method="POST">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
       
    <span>{{ form.pecas.label }}</span>
    <div class="chips" >    
    </div>
                                   
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save">
</form>
            
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.chips').chips(); 
        
    $('.chips-placeholder').chips({
     placeholder: 'Código da peça',
     secondaryPlaceholder: '+ Peça',
     class: 'pecas',
     name: 'pecas',
     });
     var chipInstance = M.Chips.getInstance($(".chips"));
     var pecas = chipInstance.chipsData
     console.log(pecas)  
     });
</script>
         
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('select').formSelect();
     });
</script>
```

**Flask route:**

```
@app.route("/add", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def add():   
            
    form = AddDispositivoForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':                
        pecas = request.form.getlist("pecas")
        print(pecas)   
                
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template("add.html", form=form)
```

**Everything I tried returned an empty list [ ]**

Comment: Can you add the full HTML code

Comment: @Mosallamy, i added as much as possible now

Comment: From the code you added I cannot see where you defined the input field for "pecas" filed

Comment: The DIV with CHIPS class generates the input automatically when rendering the HTML, I believe I should put a NAME attribute in this input that will be generated, but I still don't know how

Comment: You can see more information about the element at this link (https://materializecss.com/chips.html)